# Hyperledger Composer ecplise plugin

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Is there any eclipse plugin to support "Hyperledger Composer"? other than Visual studio code?

I'm very familiar with eclipse IDE, and I need to use it for developing Hyperledger CTO code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any Eclipse plugin for Composer.

In addition to Visual Studio Code, there is also an Atom plugin.

If you want an environment where you can integrate editing and 'immediate' testing you could try the Composer Playground online, or the Composer Playground locally with the Web Profile.  With Playground you have a simulated Fabric in the browser local storage without the weight and complexity of a real Fabric.

Comment: The most important thing for me, is the auto complete feature, which is not supported in Composer Playground online